# Creating a right substring function with JPA Criteria Builder

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I'm having a difficult time do the following with the JPA CriteriaBuilder:

```
SUBSTRING( field, LENGTH( field ) - 7 )
```

The database I am using does not have a RIGHT function, if it did I could just do the following:

```
builder.function( "RIGHT", String.class, fieldExp, builder.literal(7) );
```

But no dice. While CriteriaBuilder DOES have a substring function expression I cannot figure out how to do the substraction from LENGTH for the literal 7.

Any thoughts? TIA

Comment: What's your PostgreSQL version? [`right()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-string.html) was introduced with 9.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, got it.

```
builder = builder.substring( field, builder.diff( builder.length( field ), 7 );
```